# How to call GDALDEMProcessing from the GDAL C# wrapper?

Tags: c#, gdal

I'm trying to calculate aspect and hillshade in C# using GDAL. I have installed GDAL and GDAL.Native packages via NuGet but I could not find the GDALDEMProcessing calls (https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html) for calculating aspect and hillshade of DEM file. How to calculate aspect and hillshade in C# using GDAL?

Comment: `GDALDEMProcessing` is only exposed in the GDAL C API. C# bindings that you are using are for the C++ API. https://gdal.org/api/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GDAL wrapper function :

```
Gdal.wrapper_GDALDEMProcessing(destRaster, srcRaster, "hillshade", null, null, null, null)
```

(you can provide GDALDEMProcessingOptions as 5th parameter)